# Does anyone know how to do this shadow filter?

Tags: css, filter

does anyone know how to do this shadow filter in CSS?

[image: shadow filter]

Comment: use maybe grayscale filter: grayscale();

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It looks as though you're trying to get someone to write code for you which is not what this website is for _ Please add any code attempt that you've tried. You should also visit SO Help Center 'Asking' section to find out more about submitting a properly formatted question _ Doing this will help to ensure that your post isn't down-voted >>> stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Try working with pseudo elements like ::before & ::after
if you have a div with a className of card this would be the css solution :

```
 .card {
    position:relative
}
 .card::before {
     content:"";
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     top:0;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     background:#000;
     opacity:0.4;
}
```

You might have some issues with text and image keep in mind that giving z-index to each item will resolve it.

Learn more here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements

Comment: As well as being helpful now, this site is focused on creating useful questions and answers for all visitors in the future _ In its current state this question is not good and will likely be closed. Please read this FAQ on answering SO questions, and specifically the section on 'Answering well-asked questions' >>> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer